# Can't update a nested object's property using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

In [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) we have a best practice not modify state directly i.e. mutation...
It is also important in [Redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects)...

```
/* initial state */
export const usersStartState = { users: { isLoggedIn: false } }

export default function users(state = usersStartState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
            return Object.assign({}, state,
                state.users.isLoggedIn = true)
        case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT:
            return Object.assign({}, state,
                state.users.isLoggedIn = false)
        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

The above doesn't work, but can anyone help me how to properly update that nested objects property?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
return {...state, users:{...state.users, isLoggedIn : true}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're both mutating state and returning a new state object. You're mutating state by saying `state.users.isLoggedIn = ..`, but then returning a new state object by doing `return Object.assign(...)`.

Instead maybe just do

```js
case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT:
  return { ...state, users: { ...state.users, isLoggedIn: false }};
```

An alternative would be to create a copy of state and modify it instead

```js
// Create new object so we don't mutate state
let newState = {...state, users: {...state.users}; 
// Remember to do this for each nested object or you 
// will still be referencing that piece of the original state
switch (action.type) {
  case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
    newState.users.isLoggedIn = true; // Make your changes
    return newState; // Return new state
  case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_OUT:
    newState.users.isLoggedIn = true;
    return newState;
  default:
    return state;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to spread state.users, saw your answer and remembered. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Brian, but this `case actionTypes.users.IS_LOGGED_IN:
            return {...state, users: {...state.users, isLoggedIn: true } };` yields `{users:
isLoggedIn: false
users:
{isLoggedIn: true}}`

Comment: That return value doesn't look like a valid format? is that exactly what its returning? Or is it supposed to be `{isLoggedIn: false}, `?